# getStaticProps error with Typescript, Next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have this code:

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<HomeProps> = async () => {
    const firstCategory = 0;
    const { data }: AxiosResponse<MenuItem[]> = await axios.post(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN + '/api/top-page/find',
        {
            firstCategory,
        }
    );
    return {
        props: {
            data,
            firstCategory,
        },
    };
};

interface HomeProps extends Record<string, unknown> {
    menu: MenuItem[];
    firstCategory: number;
}
```

But I had an error:

```
Type '() => Promise<{ props: { data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticProps<HomeProps, ParsedUrlQuery>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ props: { data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPropsResult<HomeProps> | Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<HomeProps>>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ props: { data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<HomeProps>>'.
      Type '{ props: { data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'GetStaticPropsResult<HomeProps>'.
        Type '{ props: { data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: HomeProps; revalidate?: number | boolean | undefined; }'.
          Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
            Property 'menu' is missing in type '{ data: MenuItem[]; firstCategory: number; }' but required in type 'HomeProps'.ts(2322)
```

And I really don't know what is the `ParsedUrlQuery`. I tried to import it(`import { ParsedUrlQuery } from 'querystring';`). But it doesn't help.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HomeProps` contains `menu: MenuItem[]`, but then you're trying to return `data: MenuItem[]`. If the type is correct, then update the code to return this:

```
return {
  props: {
    menu: data,
    firstCategory,
  },
};
```

Or if the code is correct but the type is wrong, update the type:

```
interface HomeProps extends Record<string, unknown> {
    data: MenuItem[];
    firstCategory: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN` with the domain itself

```
const { data }: AxiosResponse<MenuItem[]> = await axios.post('https://your domain/api/top-page/find',
    {
        firstCategory,
    }
);
```

The problem is that the response does not come with the variable `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32338970)